# Can I configure eww to use pdf-view-mode (from pdf-tools) for PDFs instead of DocView?

Tags: eww, pdf

I use [pdf-tools](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools) to read PDFs inside of Emacs and greatly prefer it to DocView. I just noticed that when I try to open a URL thar points to a PDF in eww, it uses DocView instead of the pdf-view-mode from pdf-tools. This is particularly annoying since DocView fails to display the PDF! Switching the buffer to pdf-view-mode manually then succesfully shows it. Can I configure things so that eww uses pdf-view-mode on the first try?

Comment: Take a look at line 403 of the source code in the attached link:  http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/annotate/head:/lisp/net/eww.el  It may be on a different line depending on which version you are using.

Comment: Thanks, @lawlist, after I asked the question I did find that was where `doc-view-mode` was called by setting `(debug-on-entry 'doc-view-mode)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use pdf-tools (pdf-view-mode) in emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19686/how-to-use-pdf-tools-pdf-view-mode-in-emacs)

Comment: @Tyler, I'm not sure but I won't investigate whether it does or not because (1) this question was already answered in the year 2014, as you verify by scrolling down to the answer I accepted, (2) even that answer is unnecessary nowadays since with more recent versions of Emacs and pdf-tools what I wanted works out the box! (so I removed the code kindly suggested by T. Verron from my init.el a few years ago).

Comment: @Tyler Curiosity got the better of me and I read the question you suggested. The accepted answer says that this works automatically, which as I mentioned above is correct now, but wasn't in 2014 when I asked my question. So maybe the answer to whether it answers my question is "It would had I asked it now, but it didn't back in 2014". :)

Comment: @Omar I think the phrase "Does this answer your question?" gets added automatically when you flag a question as a duplicate now? I didn't enter it by hand, anyways. I did flag this as a duplicate, because the linked question serves as the canonical answer to questions of the form "how do I get pdf-tools to work for X". Of course, your question was asked and answered before the other question was, but I think it's normal to do this when a comprehensive general answer addresses an older, more specific question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Warning: dirty work-around ahead**

Since you "*greatly prefer [pdf-tools] to DocView*", is it safe to assume that using it to view all pdfs is acceptable?

The following code snippet will switch the document to `pdf-view-mode` anytime `doc-view`is entered with a `pdf` document.

```
(defvar tv/prefer-pdf-tools (fboundp 'pdf-view-mode))
(defun tv/start-pdf-tools-if-pdf ()
  (when (and tv/prefer-pdf-tools
             (eq doc-view-doc-type 'pdf))
    (pdf-view-mode)))

(add-hook 'doc-view-mode-hook 'tv/start-pdf-tools-if-pdf)
```

The behavior can be enabled or disabled by `setq`-ing the variable `tv/prefer-pdf-tools` to t or nil.

Comment: Oh, I had missed that `doc-view-mode` had a hook! I tried adivising `eww-display-pdf` and that didn't work (not sure why). I'll try your solution and report back.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This does work (after you remove the parenthesis around `tv/prefer-pdf-tools`, which is not a function).

Answer (score 3):

You can use an advise around `eww-display-pdf` to override the definition of `doc-view-mode` temporarily.  With the new `nadvice` library this is as easy as:

```
(advice-add 'eww-display-pdf
            :around (lambda (orig &rest args)
                      (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'doc-view-mode) #'pdf-view-mode))
                        (apply orig args)))
            '((name . eww-display-pdf-tools)))
```

To revert back to the original `doc-view-mode`, use `(advice-remove 'eww-display-pdf 'eww-display-pdf-tools)`.

I have opened [Emacs bug 19270](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=19270) to make the EWW PDF Mode customizable.

Comment: Cool! I tried adding advice to `eww-display-pdf` to just make it run `pdf-view-mode` `:after` it did its usual work, but that didn't work for some reason. It never occurred to me to swap out the definition of the `doc-view-mode` function (probably because I'm so used to lexical scope!).

Comment: Thanks for opening the bug report too. I would imagine lots of people would actually prefer eww to open PDFs in their customary external PDF viewer.

Answer (score 1):

I use emacs-28, eww use mailcap to open pdf, custom it by open with pdf-tools:

```
(add-to-list 'mailcap-user-mime-data
               '((type . "application/pdf")
                 (viewer . pdf-view-mode)))
```

See [Emacs - Help - pdf
viewer](http://emacs.1067599.n8.nabble.com/pdf-viewer-td466635.html) for more information.

Comment: Are you from the future? I don't think Emacs 27 has been released yet (that's the pre-release build I'm using), let alone 28.

Comment: I use archlinux with the development version of emacs:
    aur/emacs-git 28.0.50.139945-1 [installed: 28.0.50.140001-1] (74) (1.07)
        GNU Emacs. Development master branch.

Comment: Amazing. Finally a solution that works! Thank you very much!