# How to use pdf-tools (pdf-view-mode) in emacs?

Tags: org-mode, gnus, pdf, pdf-tools

[pdf-tools](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools) includes pdf-view-mode which offers several features not present in doc-view-mode (see end of question).

Can pdf-view-mode be used as a replacement for doc-view-mode generally, or does it have to be "tool" by tool?

In either case, is it necessary to edit emacs source to use pdf-tools in gnus, eww and orgmode or are their system-wide settings that can be employed?

--- Features of pdf-tools here for convenience; see [github site](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools) for details ---

1. Seems faster than doc-view
2. Resolution usually better since not being rendered as a png
3. Nice search, and can even search for all occurrences of a phrase
4. Can add text annotations, and highlighting, underlining, and the like
5. Can create imenus for pdf parts
6. Can treat several pdfs as a single "virtual" pdf
7. Can integrate with latex to see latex source and pdf side by side and jump from one to the other at the equivalent locations (e.g. select `\section{A section}` in LaTeX and got that section in pdf.

Comment: See [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3105/how-to-use-an-external-program-as-the-default-way-to-open-pdfs-from-emacs) for a related discussion which likely includes the answer to your questions.

Comment: Gnus may be a special case? See: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2015-02/msg00438.html

Comment: You might need to reword your question away from the dreaded 'best-practices', which some folks assume means answers will be primarily opinion-based. I seem to recall gnus is a special case here, and you will need to add appropriate config to .mailcap. If your question isn't closed before I get home, I'll dig up my config for you.

Comment: Gnus uses mailcap to figure out what applications to open attachments with. If you have Emacs configured to open pdf files with pdf-tools, you need to add the line `application/pdf; emacsclient %s` to `.mailcap`, and start the Emacs edit-server: invoke Emacs as `emacs --daemon`, or add `(server-start)` to your .emacs.

Comment: Thanks. That works, and after that this works for `org`. `(set 'org-file-apps
     '((auto-mode . emacs) ...
          ("\\.pdf\\'" . default)))`

Comment: Question seems clearer with the edits.  Could you list the differences in features for those of us less familiar with pdf tools?

Comment: edited question to add list of pdf-tools features

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Switching from `docview` to `pdf-tools` happens 'automatically' when you install `pdf-tools`. Once you've done this, any time Emacs tries to open a pdf *in Emacs*, it will use `pdf-tools`. However, some packages will call out to the operating system, or use different config within Emacs, to decide if they should use Emacs or another program to open a pdf. So there is some 'tool-by-tool' configuration required to get all Emacs packages to use pdf-tools.

If you want your pdfs opened in the same instance of Emacs, you need to have it running in daemon mode (i.e., start it with `emacs --daemon`), or call `(server-start)` in your init so that `emacsclient` will work.

## Org-mode links

Out of the box, `org-mode` doesn't know about pdf-tools. However, you can add support for opening org links to pdf files with [org-pdfview](https://github.com/markus1189/org-pdfview), which is available as a package on MELPA. Once it's installed, you can activate it with the following code in your `.emacs`:

```el
(eval-after-load 'org '(require 'org-pdfview))

(add-to-list 'org-file-apps 
             '("\\.pdf\\'" . (lambda (file link)
                                     (org-pdfview-open link))))
```

Doing this will provide a new completion target for adding links via `C-c C-l`, `pdfview:`, with support for jumping to specific pages. Full links use the format:

```
[[pdfview:/path/to/myfile.pdf::42][My file Description]]
```

### Interleave Mode & PDF annotations

[Interleave mode](https://github.com/rudolfochrist/interleave) provides support for presenting "your PDF side by side with an Org Mode buffer with your notes." This is an alternative to using the annotations embedded in a pdf (which you can do with pdf-tools). Instead, you end up with an org-mode file with all your annotations, which links to the page in the pdf that the annotations are associated with.

## Gnus

As I mentioned in my comment, `gnus` uses [mailcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type#Mailcap) to open attachments. To configure this, you need the following in your `.mailcap` file:

```
application/pdf; emacsclient %s
```

## EWW

EWW also uses mailcap, so modify your `.mailcap` file as per Gnus above.

## AucTeX

For AucTeX, there are a number of relevant options:

- viewers are specified via the variable `TeX-view-program-selection`: find the entry for `output-pdf` and select "PDF Tools" for the value.
- to use SyncTex, you need to:

  - set `TeX-source-correlate-mode`, either interactively by calling that function via M-x, or by setting the variable permanently via `M-x customize-variable`.
  - make sure `TeX-source-correlate-method` includes `(pdf . synctex)`

With this in place, from your tex source file `C-c C-g` should display the corresponding section of the pdf.

## ESS

Customize the variable `ess-pdf-viewer-pref` to `emacsclient`.

## xdg-open

On Linux, some packages will call the external program `xdg-open` to open pdf files. This will use your system-wide settings to determine which program to use. This is a system-wide change, so other programs will send pdf documents to Emacs when you've set this up. So if you don't want, e.g., Firefox, to do this, you won't want to make these changes.

To set emacsclient to open pdfs system-wide via `xdg-open`:

- create a file in `~/.local/share/applications/emacsclient.desktop` with the contents:

> [Desktop Entry]
>   Name=Emacs Client
>   Exec=emacsclient %u
>   Icon=emacs-icon
>   Type=Application
>   Terminal=false
>   MimeType=application/pdf;

- from the command line, issue:

`xdg-mime default emacsclient.desktop application/pdf`

You can test that this worked with `xdg-open your-document.pdf` - it should open `your-document.pdf` in Emacs.

## w3m

w3m first checks the variable `w3m-doc-view-content-types`, and if it sees "application/pdf" there, it will open pdfs in doc-view. This is a customizable variable, so remove the "application/pdf" entry using the customization interface.

Without an entry in `w3m-doc-view-content-types`, w3m next checks the variable `w3m-content-type-alist` for entries that match "application/pdf". Customize the entry to read

```
[INS] [DEL] Type: application/pdf
  Regexp: ( ) Not specified
          (*) String: \.pdf\'
  Viewer: ( ) Not specified
          (*) External viewer:
                Command: emacsclient
                Arguments:
                  [INS] [DEL] file
                  [INS]
```

You could also use an emacs function (presumably `find-file` or similar), rather than an external call to `emacsclient`, but I couldn't figure out the syntax for that.

Comment: However w3m in emacs still uses docview. Any advice how to fix that one?

Comment: see the updated answer

Comment: Can I link from `org-mode` to a particular annotation in the PDF file?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning not that I'm aware of. Interleave mode provides support for recording annotations in a separate, linked, org-mode file. I'll update the answer