# how can you open pdf in eww?

Tags: terminal-emacs, pdf, eww

I have seen this post

[Can I configure eww to use pdf-view-mode (from pdf-tools) for PDFs instead of DocView?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4089/can-i-configure-eww-to-use-pdf-view-mode-from-pdf-tools-for-pdfs-instead-of-do)

> I just noticed that when I try to open a URL thar points to a PDF in eww, it uses DocView instead of the pdf-view-mode from pdf-tools.

How can one do that? when I open URL that points to pdf it stops.

xdg-open: unexpected option '-'
Try 'xdg-open --help' for more information.

I am using tty only so I am guessing the original poster's setup is what I need?

Comment: What to you mean tty only?

Comment: I am using emacs without gui. I am not sure if emacs nox and using emacs in tty environment is the same thing so I said tty only.

Comment: I think you may have formed an incorrect expectation about eww's capabilities. If you are using tty only, what do you expect/hope eww will do with a PDF?

Comment: I thought there might be some plugin that can translate pdf into text. Thanks for the heads up!